# Xamarin Forms for IOS use native resolution

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created my first Xamarin Forms App targetting UWP and IOS.

The UI was originally designed for UWP to target a 1920x1080 screen and when IOS on an iPad was added we identified that the ones we are interested in have a minimum of 2048x1536 screens, so the same design *should* fit onto the iPad quite comfortably.

Unfortunately, when the app is deployed to a brand new iPad and even iPad Pro then the UI shows effectively 1024x768.

The UI does allow for low resolutions but we don't want to be restricted to such a ridiculous resolution as 1024x768 when we have 2048x1536 available on the iPad and 2732x2048 available on the iPad Pro

So the app is scaling to 2x or 3x, (which is terrible on the iPad Pro).

I have seen many suggestions to use a LaunchScreen.xib to tell iOS that the app is allowed a resolution but when I try to research this I find that it is deprecated. I created a LaunchScreen.storyboard but this has not helped.

**So my (2-part) question is as follows...**

Is there actually a way to convince iOS to use 1x scaling?

If so could anyone point me in the direction of some **current** documentation about how to make it work?

Comment: Why you want to use actual resolution? For our developers, we use point system to develop our apps. It means even though we use 1024x768 when developing, it will render to 2048x1536 if it runs on a device with 2048x1536 resolution.

Comment: Hi @Land. The trouble is that I don't seem to be seeing the UI expand to use all 2048x1536 pixels. It is still treating the device like it only has 1024x768. So in the Pro especially we end up a UI that looks ridiculously large. (I will try to get screenshots to illustrate the issue)

Comment: It's better to help us understand your issue if you could post some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation and hair pulling it would seen that iOS just "knows" how big its physical pixels are and it won't let you switch off scaling.

Our next best course of action was to reduce font sizes by 20%, cut back on whitespace and then finally explicitly change what still didn't fit.